# Updating date field based on interval of other date field

Tags: sql, window-functions, greenplum

I have the following fields:

```
   implement_dt    approval_dt    phase
    3/31/2018      12/31/2017       1
    3/31/2019      12/31/2017       2
    3/31/2020      12/31/2017       3
```

I'm trying to recalculate the `approval_dt` based on the intervals of the `implement_dt` to: (And I can't just add the phase to the `approval_dt` because some intervals are larger than 1 year)

```
   implement_dt    approval_dt    phase
    3/31/2018      12/31/2017       1
    3/31/2019      12/31/2018       2
    3/31/2020      12/31/2019       3
```

I've basically managed to do that using this code:

```
select *
, case when phase = 1 then approval_dt
       when phase > 1 then approval_dt + balance
       else null
       end as new_date       
from (
select *
, sum(changes) over (order by phase) as balance
from (
select *
, implement_dt - lag(implement_dt) over (order by phase) as changes
from chk1
) x
) y
;
```

This works except when the `approval_dt` is `12/31` in a leap year. Using the above code, my results are:

```
   implement_dt    approval_dt    phase
    3/31/2018      12/31/2017       1
    3/31/2019      12/31/2018       2
    3/31/2020       1/1/2020        3
```

The difference in days between `3/31/2019` and `3/31/2020` is 366 days. I need the `1/1/2020` to be `12/31/2019`.

I've tried variations of using the year differences between the `implement_dt` instead of days and multiplying that by 365 to get "clean years" but I keep getting an error in line 3:

```
select *
, case when phase = 1 then approval_dt
       when phase > 1 then approval_dt + balance
       else null
       end as new_date       
from (
select *
, (sum(changes) over (order by phase)::bigint)*365 as balance
from (
select *
, extract(year from implement_dt) - lag(extract(year from implement_dt)) over (order by phase) as changes
from chk1
) x
) y
;

ERROR:  operator does not exist: date + bigint
LINE 3:        when phase > 1 then approval_dt + balance
                                               ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm using pgAdmin with PostgreSQL in Greenplum. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to add a number of days to approval_dt, then use `approval_dt + interval '1' day * balance::int`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this company - I'm using pgAdmin which uses PostgresSQL to access a database which is in Green Plum - I'm not sure how the mechanics work.

Comment: I was able to get your suggestion to work for when the approval_dt is 12/31/yyyy. Thank you.